# How to revert remote bare repository on git

Tags: git

I've done the process described at this link http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto
It works like a charm, but now I have to revert, temporarily, the remote repository (and the checkout) to a previous state.
I think that I probably just need to revert locally and push (and the checkout will work properly) but I'm not sure.
Notice that it is not a definitive revert, just a temporary one (think of it as if I pushed the latest changes to production before I should)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your local repository use `git reset --mixed <commit>` then `git push --force` to the remote. You may need to stash the uncommitted changes first.

From the [git-reset manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-reset):

> --mixed
>
> Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved
>   but not marked for commit) and reports what has not been
>   updated. This is the default action.

Comment: @filaruina Don't use this if you want a "temporary revert" as you name it.

Comment: @KurzedMetal Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I ran a series of tests and `--mixed` seems to have the desired effect.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! Although I might add that an -f in git push is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Reset your local master (assuming it's the master branch you want to revert of course) branch to your previous commit and push it to the server with -f or --force

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: Reset --hard is not temporary, it changes the working tree, not a temporary change. I used --mixed and it worked. Anyway, git push has to be --force or it won't work, thanks.

Comment: Your question never said that you needed to keep the working tree intact. Reset --hard can be temporary as long as you don't want to reset uncommitted changes. You can always undo a reset by resetting the reset so to speak. But sure, --mixed is the way to go. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer on that. Wish I could select both answers as accepted. Anyway, thanks!